# Scope_Identity outside of transaction

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking at some SQL in a stored procedure I've inherited, and a it has me scratching my head:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddPerson] 
(   @Name NVARCHAR(22),
    @Age INT
)
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person]
    ([Name], [Age])
    VALUES
    (@Name, @Age);
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM [dbo].[Person]
        WHERE [PersonId] = @newId;
```

Is there some value to the transaction here that I don't understand? I'm certainly no DBA, but transactions should be ensuring transactional behaviour of multiple commands, no?

Comment: This transaction is totally pointless, since the `INSERT` in itself would be run in an implicit transaction *anyway* ....

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I wasn't sure if there was some effect on `SCOPE_IDENTITY` that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Also unless there is an insert trigger on the table selecting the entire row that was just inserted is kind of pointless. I don't like seeing select * for a number of reasons but in this case it is silly. It will only have the two columns you inserted values for plus the identity. It could just as easily be a select of the 2 variables plus SCOPE_IDENTITY. No need to hit the base table.

Comment: I would also recommend against storing age. You should instead store birthdate. When you store Age it is always stale information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction has no effect on `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, which returns

> the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)